# Find the number of binary strings of length $n$ in which every block of 0s is followed by a block of 1s with the same parity of length.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of binary strings of length $p_n, n \in N$ in which every blockof 0s is followed by a block of 1s with the same parity of length.

1. Determine the generating function $P(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty p_n x^n$
2. Show that if $n \geq 2$, then $p_n = 2 \cdot 3^{\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor - 1} $

I tried to write out a regular expression
$$1^*0(00)^*1(11)^* \cup 1^* 00(00)^*11(11)^*\cup 1^*$$

But it does not seem to produce the correct $p_n$.

$$\begin{align*}
P(x) & = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)^2 x^2}{1-x}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)^2 x^4}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1-x} \\
& = -\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2 (x-1)^3}-\frac{3}{8 (x+1)}+\frac{1}{4 (x+1)^2}-\frac{13}{8 (x-1)}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: For a combinatorial proof: a string has the property "every block of $0$s is followed by a block of $1$'s with the same parity" if and only if the string can be split into pairs of adjacent characters which are all either `00`, `01`, or `11` if $n$ is even, and with an additional `1` at the end if $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a single block of zeros, whereas the strings are supposed to have any number of blocks of zeros, each followed by a block of ones with the same parity of length.

The generating function for one block of zeros followed by one block of ones with the same parity of length is $\frac{x^2+x^4}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}$, so the generating function for any number of repetitions of this is

$$
\frac1{1-\frac{x^2+x^4}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}}=\frac{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}{1-3x^2}\;.
$$

Preceding this with an arbitrary number of ones yields another factor $\frac1{1-x}$, so the complete generating function is

$$
\frac{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}{\left(1-3x^2\right)(1-x)}=\frac{(1+x)\left(1-x^2\right)}{1-3x^2}\;.
$$

For the second part, write this as

$$
\frac13+\frac x3+\frac23\frac{1+x}{1-3x^2}\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Your answer suggests a binary string of $1^*\left(00(00)^*11(11)^* \cup 0(00)^*1(11)^*\right)^*$. If I write my binary string like this: $1^*\left( 0(00)^*1(11)^* \right)^* \cup 1^* \left( 00(00)^*11(11)^* \right)^* \cup 1^*$. It gets very complicated and doesn't seem to produce the answer above. Could you point out my error?

Comment: Sorry, there is a bracket mismatch.$\left( 1^* \left( 0(00)^*1(11)^*\right)^* \right) \cup \left( 1^* \left( 00(00)^*11(11)^*\right)^* \right) \cup 1^*$

Comment: @Benjamin: The error is that you're only generating strings that contain only odd-parity runs and strings that contain only even-parity runs, but no strings that contain runs with both parities. You're also counting the strings generated by $1^*$ three times.